# onActivated event fires after windows closing in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am making chrome extension which monitor user's activity during web browsing. I put some listeners for tab create, tab remove, tab activate and works fine. Problem is when I close windows with more tabs, console shows this:
[image]

All tabs from windowID 1 normally close but after window closing there is an error which leads to lines 67 and 61 where is listener onActivated

```
    chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo){  
        return chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){ // LINE 61 
            return post_to_console({
                timestamp: gimme_timestamp(),
                activity: "TAB_ACTIVATED",
                winid: activeInfo.windowId,
                tabid: activeInfo.tabId,
                url: tab.url,  // LINE 67
                user_id: _user_id,
                fromindex: "undefined",
                toindex: "undefined"
            });
        });
});
```

I am not sure but I think that after tab and window closing onActivated event fires.
Here is code for closing tab and closing window:

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tab, removeInfo){
        _winid = removeInfo.windowId;
        _tabid = tab;
return post_to_console({
        timestamp: gimme_timestamp(),
        activity: "CLOSE_TAB",
        winid: _winid,
        tabid: _tabid,
        url: "undefined",
        user_id: _user_id,
        fromindex: "undefined",
        toindex: "undefined"
  });  
});
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(win){
    return post_to_console({
        timestamp: gimme_timestamp(),
        activity: "CLOSE_WINDOW",
        winid: win,
        tabid: "undefined",
        url: "undefined",
        user_id: _user_id,
        fromindex: "undefined",
        toindex: "undefined"
  }); 
});
```

I understand that chrome.tabs.get throws error because in that time window with its tabs no more exist but why after all is called onActivated event.
I appreciate any help from us. Thanks

Comment: Chrome API is asynchronous, so `chrome.tabs.get` callback is executed after the current event queue (closing of the tab) is processed, I think.

Comment: but closing the tab and closing the window, any of them dont involve chrome.tabs.get so it is strange why it jumps to that event / listener

Comment: I can only guess what happens under the hood: each window has at least one tab (that's a fact), so when a window is closed the last tab (or rather the first tab of that window) remains and gets activated temporarily, then the window is destroyed along with the last tab.